# Is necessary check also for ExistSync(), if already check with AccessSync() method from fs node a file?

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm writing a function that check for valid and existing file in node, so my question is: Does my function really needs to use fs.ExistSync() if i already use this method fs.AccessSync()

Comment: Im not sure I understand what are you talking about.
If you already checked if the file exists, why would you run it again?

Comment: If a user can't read the directory that the file is in, the user can't read the file.  I don't think existSync is fucked up enough to actually hack through user permissions, so actually knowing if a file exists is probably bullshit from the node fs.existsSync perspective.

Comment: Yeah sure, I just wanted know your opinions, however is kind of weird name a function fileExists and use a function to check access permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call `existsSync` if you've already called `accessSync`. In fact the [implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b5a136cd67e39411bb16ae78f7d972846d12e55f/lib/fs.js#L257) of `existsSync` shows that the same [function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b5a136cd67e39411bb16ae78f7d972846d12e55f/lib/fs.js#L219) as `accessSync` is used internally - the only difference are the flags that you've provided to `accessSync`, `existsSync` always calls the access function with the `F_OK` flag:

existsSync:

```
binding.access(nPath, F_OK, undefined, ctx);
```

accessSync:

```
binding.access(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path), mode, undefined, ctx);
```